# c - multiple line input

Tags: c, input, line

I don't actually have a lot of code to show here, but I can NOT seem to get a realistic answer on this: How can i take in multiple line input from a user?

for example i might want a user to say something like...

```
 name: command
       command
       command 
       command

 name: command
       command 
       command
```

(the number of commands is NOT known. actually that would really have to do with the # of lines.) I just have no idea where to begin because there doesnt seem to be many resources on the matter)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
do {
    read a line and put it into String variable s
    Push s into an array
} while (s is not empty)
Remove the last element of the array
```

As I haven't written C for months, this is what I can do now.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum { MAX_LINES = 100 };
char *lines[MAX_LINES];
int nlines;

char buffer[4096];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0 && nlines < MAX_LINES)
{
    if (buffer[0] == '\n')
        break;
    if ((lines[nlines++] = strdup(buffer)) == 0)
        ...memory allocation failed...
}
```

The lines of commands are in `lines[0]` .. `lines[nlines-1]`.  If you don't like the hard-wired limit on the number of lines, dynamically allocate the `lines` array of pointers (exercise for the reader).